# rust calling failure::fail_bounds_check with no-landing-pads flag enabled

Tags: operating-system, rust

I have been trying to write a basic kernel in rust and the link script fails with the following error:
`roost.rs:(.text.kmain+0x12a): undefined reference to 'failure::fail_bounds_check::hee3207bbe41f708990v::v0.11.0'`

I compile the rust source files with the following flags:

-O --target i686-unknown-linux-gnu -Z no-landing-pads --crate-type lib --emit=obj

If I understand the rust compiler correctly the -Z no-landing-pads option should stop the compiler from generating the failure functions. From testing I can tell that the failure function is only generated when the kmain function calls my function io::write_char(c: char)

This is the definition of io::write_char(c: char)

```
pub fn write_char(c: char) {
    unsafe {
    vga::place_char_at(c, vga::cursor_x, vga::cursor_y);

    vga::cursor_y =
        if vga::cursor_x >= vga::VGA_WIDTH {
            vga::cursor_y + 1
        } else {
            vga::cursor_y
        };
    vga::cursor_x = 
        if vga::cursor_x >= vga::VGA_WIDTH {
            0
        } else {
            vga::cursor_x + 1
        };

    vga::set_cursor_location(vga::cursor_x, vga::cursor_y);
    }
}
```

How can I stop rust from trying to call the nonexistant function failure::fail_bounds_check?

Edit: further testing indicates that the vga::place_char_at function is the cause. Here is the code:

```
pub fn place_char_at(c: char, x: u8, y: u8) {
    let tmpx = 
        if x >= VGA_WIDTH {
            VGA_WIDTH - 1
        } else {
            x
        };
    let tmpy = 
        if y >= VGA_HEIGHT {
            VGA_HEIGHT - 1
        } else {
            y
        };
    unsafe {
        (*SCREEN)[(tmpy as uint) * 80 + (tmpx as uint)].char = c as u8;
    }
}
```

From what I can tell the issue is that rust wants to bound check the array access I'm doing, is there a way to turn the assure the compiler that the checks have been done or turn off the feature for that function?

Edit2: So I solved it after some work. After digging around in the docs I found that rust has a function for vector access that bypasses bound checking. To use it I changed the place_char_at function to this:

```
pub fn place_char_at(c: char, x: u8, y: u8) {
    let tmpx = 
        if x >= VGA_WIDTH {
            VGA_WIDTH - 1
        } else {
            x
        };
    let tmpy = 
        if y >= VGA_HEIGHT {
            VGA_HEIGHT - 1
        } else {
            y
        };
    unsafe {
        (*SCREEN).unsafe_mut_ref((tmpy as uint) * 80 + (tmpx as uint)).char = c as u8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described the type of SCREEN but if it implements MutableVector trait, what you probably want is to use an unsafe_set ( http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/trait.MutableVector.html#tymethod.unsafe_set ):

`unsafe fn unsafe_set(self, index: uint, val: T)`

`This performs no bounds checks, and it is undefined behaviour if index is larger than the length of self. However, it does run the destructor at index. It is equivalent to self[index] = val.`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're linking to libcore. Also libcore has one dependency: a definition of failure. Make sure you mark a function `#[lang="begin_unwind"]` somewhere in your exception code. The requirement is that `begin_unwind` not return. [See here](https://github.com/alexchandel/rustboot/blob/master/src/arch/x86/cpu/exception.rs) for my example.

> is there a way to ... turn off the feature for that function?

Nope. In the words of bstrie, [if there were a compiler flag to eliminate array bounds checks, then bstrie would fork the language and make the flag delete your hard drive](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/4047). In other words, safety is paramount.